# Did Disney's Mulan (1998) invent the "You bow to no one" moment?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, disney

Towards the end of *Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King* (2003), the Hobbits bow to newly-crowned king Aragorn. He tells them they "bow to no one," kneels for the Hobbits, and then everyone in attendance at the coronation follows suit in kneeling.

Towards the end of Disney's *Mulan* (1998) we have a similar scene, where the emperor bows to Mulan, and then the large crowds around bow to the floor for Mulan.

Was Disney's *Mulan* the first film to feature such a scene?

Comment: See also: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80941/why-did-they-bow-before-the-hobbits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disney’s *Mulan* didn’t invent it, but apparently is now known as the “[Kneel Before Frodo](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KneelBeforeFrodo)” trope according to the website [*TV Tropes*](https://tvtropes.org); bold emphasis is mine.

> In many stories involving [royalty](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RoyalBlood) (but particularly movies), there is a scene where someone is standing in a crowd of people. **As part of a [Moment of Awesome](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/SugarWiki/MomentOfAwesome), and sometimes preceding an [Awesome Moment of Crowning](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AwesomeMomentOfCrowning), the camera pulls back, and the entire crowd kneels before the character, moving in a pleasingly symmetrical wave as they do so. The character, who may have appeared minor seconds before, becomes the focus of the scene.** This is usually because of one of two circumstances: either the character is a king, princess, or someone else to whom they *should* normally kneel, but in an unexpected situation; **or the character is someone to whom they would *not* normally kneel, but unexpectedly do.**
>
> In the first instance, the character is a [King Incognito](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KingIncognito) who has just thrown off his disguise, or the subject of a [Really Royalty Reveal](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ReallyRoyaltyReveal). **In the second, the actual king may have humbled himself and bowed to the lowly hero who has just saved the kingdom. By courtesy, everyone else will imitate the king and go along with it.** Commonly, in this case, an antagonist will [also be forced to kneel to the hero](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumiliationConga), whom they have recently insulted.

And apparently this has always been a thing in the military, where war heroes and martyrs are saluted by everyone regardless of rank.

When all is said and done, the enormity of actions that have positively affected others has pushed others to bow to — and acknowledge — them as an acknowledgment of said actions and their importance to their lives/world.

Answer (score 6):

The scene in the *Lord of the Rings* movie is based on a similar scene in the book, so it predates *Mulan* by about 50–60 years.

Comment: The moment in the book is quite different. The hobbits do not attempt to bow, Aragorn says nothing about bowing or not bowing, and the assembled host does not bow. “And then to Sam’s surprise and utter confusion [Aragorn] bowed his knee before them; and taking them by the hand, Frodo upon his right and Sam upon his left, he led them to the throne, and setting them upon it, he turned to the men and captains who stood by and spoke, so that his voice rang over all the host, crying: ‘Praise them with great praise!’”

Comment: Thanks, but I was aware of this scene from the book when I wrote the question, and I agree with @ToddWilcox that it is a different idea.